# Is it possible to mount APFS (Apple's newest file system) in Ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: filesystem, mac

I've tried retroactively mounting it using

```
mount -t hfplus
```

but I get a 'wrong fs type' error.
Is it yet possible to mount APFS without commercial software?

Comment: Did you try with these? It is a paid one, but if you need it ;) https://www.paragon-software.com/business/apfs-linux/

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 appears to mount it successfully by default. However, it is read-only.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No, and it probably won't be possible for a long while. From [Apple's APFS FAQ](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/APFS_Guide/FAQ/FAQ.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016999-CH6-DontLinkElementID_1):

> **Is APFS open source?**
>
> An open source implementation is not available at this time. Apple plans to document and publish the APFS volume format specification.

So after Apple releases the APFS specs (at some unspecified date), someone will have to do the implementation work, and it would probably take many years before it attains a decent level of functionality (especially if you want write access).

Comment: There you go: [Apple File System Reference](https://developer.apple.com/support/apple-file-system/Apple-File-System-Reference.pdf)

Comment: @MCCCS No. This is just an API reference, not the filesystem specifications. It is for people who write software to interact with the filesystem through the OS X drivers, *not* to write new drivers.

Answer (score 9):

If you are willing to compile from source, you can try `apfs-fuse` from [Github](https://github.com/sgan81/apfs-fuse).

The author warns that it is in an early stage and read-only, but therefore shouldn't damage the disk you try to mount. To get just one or two files read from an Apple volume, it might be OK.