# Can I "Help" the Ubuntu 20.04 Installer Find the Existing OS?

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, macbook-pro, custom-installer

I am [still trying](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1241689/installation-of-20-04-on-late-2011-macbook-pro-installer-fails-to-recognize-ex) to install Ubuntu 20.04 on my **late-2011 17" macbook pro**. I need to install Ubuntu **alongside** my macOS High Sierra install that currently is the only other (meaningful) occupant of the 2TB SSD.

The issue (for me) is that the Ubuntu 20.04 installer incorrectly concludes:

`This computer currently has no detected operating systems.`

I currently have [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) installed on this machine - which I did in anticipation of the Ubuntu install.

Why does the Ubuntu 20.04 installer fail to recognize the huge 750GB APFS partition as an installed OS? Is there anything I can reasonably do to "help" the installer see this, and install Ubuntu in the proper location?

Comment: The installer probably cannot read APFS, which is a proprietary Apple product, so it has no idea what's on that partition.

Comment: Because [Apple won't open source the file system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/991695/is-it-possible-to-mount-apfs-apples-newest-file-system-in-ubuntu-17-10)

Comment: @user535733 & Nmath: OK - that makes sense - I understand that APFS is a closed system (Assle is dismal in this respect), but are you also saying there is no way to install Ub20.04 on this system?  The Ub20.04 page *suggests* this is possible - even mentioning a special "`Mac image`" - which I could never find. Surely there is a work-around?

Comment: @Nmath: Are there any "remedies" or alternate approaches for accomplishing my end objective (dual boot macOS & Ub20.04) on this machine?

Comment: Also: if I boot from the "Live System" I created on a USB stick, and run the `Disks` app in the Live system, it shows an EFI partition, **and** a ***750 GB APFS partition***. How could the installer *not* know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at my answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1245535/1075751). I don't have the same machine as you so I can't try this out myself, but here are my suspicions:

- As already mentioned in the comments, the Ubuntu installer cannot detect macOS because of the APFS formatting. This is not a problem though, because you can select "Something Different" as the install location and choose a previously created partition (see my linked answer).
- From what I understand about the differences between our hardware (with / without T2-chip), you can follow my answer and just **skip step "Boot and Install Ubuntu"#1**.

You may have already made some changes to your system that you want to revert before following my instructions. To remove rEFInd, follow [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1139054). To remove entries in the EFI partition that the Ubuntu installer may have created, enter the following instructions in your Mac terminal (one after another):

```
sudo diskutil mount disk0s1
cd /Volumes/EFI/EFI
rm -r boot ubuntu
cd ~
diskutil unmount disk0s1
```

If there is no entry, you'll receive an error message at the `rm`-part (which is fine).

Comment: Apologies for delayed feedback. Will try this tomorrow & be in touch.

Comment: Thanks for this - I was finally able to work through the install with some help from @DavidAnderson (see the chat record). Bottom line is your answer works perfectly, but there's a rough and confusing part when it comes to `ubiquity -b` (see chat for details). I'm selecting this as the correct answer, but please do try to make some edits on the [answer you link to from above](https://askubuntu.com/a/1245535/1075751).

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @Seamus! I've updated the linked answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

1. Disable Full disk encryption.
2. Install [rEFInd](https://sourceforge.net/projects/refind/) and power off your computer. Turn it back on. DO NOT RESTART.
3. Make some free space by shrinking the partition with macOS. Do not turn this into a partition. Just leave it unallocated.
4. Select install alongside MacOS option. If this does not appear, check whether you are installing Ubuntu in the same firmware mode as MacOS. (Either UEFI or Legacy BIOS). You will not see this option if you have MacOS in UEFI and try to install Ubuntu in Legacy and vice versa. DO not proceed if this option doesn't appear.
5. Alternatively, you can try the Something else option and partition manually. Even if you do this make sure that install alongside Ubuntu option is available.

Read [how to install and dual boot Linux on a mac](https://www.howtogeek.com/187410/how-to-install-and-dual-boot-linux-on-a-mac/) and [How to Dual Boot Linux on Your Mac and Take Back Your Powerhouse Apple Hardware](https://lifehacker.com/how-to-dual-boot-linux-on-your-mac-and-take-back-your-p-5934942)

Comment: Could you provide more detail on this statement in Step 2: `Turn it back on. DO NOT RESTART.`  It's not clear to me how to shrink a partition without starting macOS.

Comment: @Seamus I mean do not select the restart from power options. Shut down your Mac — a full shut down, not a restart — and boot it back up again. You should see the rEFInd boot manager screen. I assume you know how to install it? If you don't open a Terminal window by pressing Command + Space and, typing Terminal, and pressing Enter. Drag and drop the install.sh file from the downloaded zip file into the terminal window and press Enter to run it.

Comment: @Seamus Ah sorry. You have already installed it. And I assume that you have already shut down and turned on your computer by now. If your drive encryption is off, you can skip steps 1 and 2

Comment: @Seamus I think your problem is explained in step 4...